# Regex how to match if a substring and additional characters are present

Tags: regex

I want to match all strings that have a certain substring in it, plus more characters after the string.

For example, if the string I want to match is `'projects/'`, I want to get all strings that are for example `'projects/wood', 'projects/outdoors', 'projects/metal'`, but not match things that just say `'projects/'`

How could I go about doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.+` to match at least one character:

```
projects/.+
```